# RecursionError when using email-validator library in python

Tags: python, pandas, email-validation

Reposting a previous question for clarity.
I'm trying to use the email-validator library in python to validate a list of emails in an excel document. Here is a photo of what my data resembles and the validation column output I'd like to create: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3e4E.png)

When I run the following code on a single email, the code works just fine. I get "Valid" when the email is valid and "Invalid" when it is not. The following successfully prints "Valid":

```
import email_validator
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError

testemail = "jane.doe@gmail.com"
try:
    emailobject = validate_email(testemail)
    testemail = emailobject.email
    print("Valid")

except EmailNotValidError:
    print("Invalid")
```

But I want to run this validation technique on a pandas dataframe. When I write a function to apply to the emails column of my dataframe, I consistently get the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The following function always returns this error, even though my test email column consists of just three email rows:

```
def validate_email(em):
    try:
        emailobject = validate_email(em)
        em = emailobject.email
        print("Valid")

    except EmailNotValidError:
        print("Invalid")
```

```
df["Validation"] = df["Email"].apply(validate_email)
```

Why am I getting this error? It's only three rows of data; I don't understand why this error would occur. If I am doing something wrong or if there is a better way to use the email-validator library on my dataframe, I would love to know. I greatly appreciate any and all help.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `validate_email(em)` in the first snippet? And why do you name your function `validate_email` in the second?

Comment: It's a method from the email-validator library. Sorry for the confusion, just updated my code with the import email_validator code in there.

Comment: def validate_email(em) Calls itself for ever. What else could happen? , change the name in the def to resolve. Also your funtion is not returning anything just prints

Comment: Ugh, dumb mistake. That's why we ask questions haha. It is resolved now, thank you.